# Strange program and debugger if statement behavior

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, if-statement

This is a sanity check because I've lost mine.

I have a method `IsCaptured()` which compares an enum state member to a given value and returns a `bool`. I use this in conjunction with a mouse threshold check to determine if a drag begin message should be sent and a drag operation begun. The problem is this is being triggered on mouse move when it shouldn't be. I've added trace messages as follows:

```
TRACE(L"%s\n", (IsCaptured()) ? L"true" : L"false");
CPoint delta = pt - m_trackMouse;
static CPoint thresh(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXDRAG), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYDRAG));

if (IsCaptured() &&
    abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x || abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y)
{
    TRACE(L"%s\n", (IsCaptured()) ? L"true" : L"false");
    // Send message to enter drag mode
    bool bDrag = ::SendMessage(m_trackWnd, WM_DD_BEGIN, ::GetDlgCtrlID(m_trackWnd), (LPARAM)(void*)&m_info) != 0;

    // ...
}
```

Now the strange part, the output:

```
false
false
```

The method is implemented like so and `m_dragState` is set to `NONE` until there is a button down intercepted:

```
enum { NONE, CAPTURED, DRAGGING };
bool IsCaptured() const { return m_dragState == CAPTURED; }
```

I've tried rebuilding the entire solution to no avail. I'm running VS2010 Debug 64-bit and the program is a single threaded MFC app. What the $@#! is going on here?

Comment: Gratuitous use of parenthesis is your friend :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing strange in your output. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, which is why your

```
if (IsCaptured() &&
    abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x || abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y)
```

is interpreted as

```
if ((IsCaptured() && abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x) || 
    abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y)
```

I.e. if the `abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y` condition is met, then the result of the entire `if` condition does not depend on your `IsCaptured()` at all.

The compiler does not care that you "expressed" your intent in line breaks. Operator precedence matters. Line breaks don't.

What you apparently were intending to do was

```
if (IsCaptured() && 
    (abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x || abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y))
```

Note the placement of extra braces around the operands of `||` subexpression.

Comment: I thought since it had higher precedence it would short circuit on false since it's left to right and false logical-and anything should be false. I'll add some parens and see if that changes things though.

Comment: @AJG85: The `&&` subexpression will indeed short-circuit on `false`. That means that `abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x` will not be evaluated when `IsCaptured()` is `false`. But that's all it means. It does not cancel the further evaluation (why would it?). Since the `&&` subexpression evaluates to `false`, the `||` *does not* short-circuit and proceeds to evaluate its second operand, i.e. `abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y`.

Comment: @AJG85: Short-circuiting can eliminate some *side-effects* of a logical expression, but it can never affect its *result*. If the expression should evaluate to `true` from purely mathematical point of view, then it will evaluate to `true` in C/C++ as well. This is an axiom not affected by short-circuiting in any way. An expression that looks like `(whatever) || true` will always evaluate to `true`, regardless of any short-circuiting inside "whatever".

Answer (score 1):

Think of this as:

```
(IsCaptured() && abs(delta.x) >= thresh.x || abs(delta.y) >= thresh.y)
```

this:

```
 (false && true) || true
```

Your IsCaptured() doesn't have to be true to progress, so it can quite possibly be false in both printouts.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make sure first that the two false's do not refer both to the first trace line.

If the second trace line is actually printing false here, you probably have a classic race condition on your hands and need to protect against it.

Comment: There are no threads involved here I have breakpoints on the entrance of `OnMouseMove`, `OnButtonDown`, and the line that sends the message above. `CAPTURED` never gets set as the breakpoint for `OnButtonDown` never gets hit meanwhile it waltzes through this as if `IsCaptured()` returned true.